Cannot stream data from one MySQL database to another via Apache Flink (java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data)
I'm a full-stack dev, but my company would like to explore benefits of some patterns (change data capture, which is new to me).
For this reason I'm trying to build a simple Java job for Apache Flink.
The goal is simple: given a source database, which contains one table (notes), the job should detect changes, filter results under certain criteria and send them to a destination database in the same table.
Apache Flink and MySQL instances are running via Docker Compose.
Here's the docker-compose.yaml file (I've kept usernames and passwords because this is just a playground project):
name: cdc-flink
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:latest
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    volumes:
      - ./packages/flink/flink-sql-connector-mysql-cdc-3.2.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-connector-mysql-cdc-3.2.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-table-api-java-bridge-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table-api-java-bridge-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-table-planner-loader-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table-planner-loader-1.20.0-jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-connector-jdbc-3.2.0-1.19.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-connector-jdbc-3.2.0-1.19.jar
      - ./packages/flink/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:/opt/flink/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-streaming-java-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-streaming-java-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-connector-base-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-connector-base-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-table-runtime-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-table-runtime-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-clients-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-clients-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-core-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-core-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-java-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-java-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/flink-json-1.20.0.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-json-1.20.0.jar
      - ./packages/flink/config.yaml:/opt/flink/conf/config.yaml
  taskmanager:
    image: flink:latest
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    links:
      - "jobmanager:jobmanager"
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
  
  # SQL databases
  mysql-source:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db-source
    volumes:
      - ./init/db-source:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./volumes/mysql/source:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - 3307:3306
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  mysql-destination-a:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db-destination-a
    volumes:
      - ./init/db-destination:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./volumes/mysql/destination-a:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - 3308:3306
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  mysql-destination-b:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db-destination-b
    volumes:
      - ./init/db-destination:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./volumes/mysql/destination-b:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - 3309:3306
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

A couple more details:

Flink conf.yaml is overwritten so that taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots is 10 and not 1, otherwise I would receive an error (cannot obtain resources)
mappings defined for jobmanager services should be correct
MySQL instances are up and running and

service db-source contains database source
database source contains table notes
structure of table notes is

id (int, pk)
destination (nullable string)
content (nullable string)





The code of my Java job is made of just two classes:
public class CopyNotes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings
                .newInstance()
                .inStreamingMode()
                .build();

        TableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
        tableEnv.createTable("source", SqlDescriptors.SourceDatabase);
        tableEnv.createTable("destination_a", SqlDescriptors.DestinationA);

        Table source = tableEnv
                .from("source")
                .filter($("destination").isEqual("a"))
                .select($("id"), $("content"));

        TablePipeline pipeline = source
                .insertInto("destination_a");

        pipeline.printExplain();
        pipeline.execute();
    }
}

public class SqlDescriptors {
    public static final TableDescriptor SourceDatabase =
            TableDescriptor.forConnector("mysql-cdc")
                    .schema(
                            Schema.newBuilder()
                                    .column("id", DataTypes.INT().notNull())
                                    .column("destination", DataTypes.STRING().nullable())
                                    .column("content", DataTypes.STRING().nullable())
                                    .primaryKey("id")
                                    .build()
                    )
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.HOSTNAME, "db-source")
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.PORT, 3306)
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.USERNAME, "root")
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.PASSWORD, "root")
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.DATABASE_NAME, "source")
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.TABLE_NAME, "notes")
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                    .option(MySqlSourceOptions.SERVER_ID, "5800-5900")
                    .build();

    public static final TableDescriptor DestinationA =
            TableDescriptor.forConnector("jdbc")
                    .schema(
                            Schema.newBuilder()
                                    .column("id", DataTypes.BIGINT().notNull())
                                    .column("content", DataTypes.STRING().nullable())
                                    .primaryKey("id")
                                    .build())
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.URL, "jdbc:mysql://db-destination-a:3306/destination")
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.SINK_PARALLELISM, 1)
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.TABLE_NAME, "notes")
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.USERNAME, "root")
                    .option(JdbcConnectorOptions.PASSWORD, "root")
                    .build();
}

If I package and upload the job, Flink does not complain, but it raises an exception when trying to run the job (which should happen right after submission, which seems to be caused by this error:
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data

Do you have any suggestion / observation?
Note: here's the complete error stack trace
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailureAndReport(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:281)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:265)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:515)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(PekkoRpcActor.java:318)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(PekkoRpcActor.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:229)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:174)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot instantiate user function.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:416)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:169)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.<init>(RegularOperatorChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:789)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:771)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:970)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:939)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:763)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:533)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:521)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:475)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:400)
    ... 9 more

I tried writing the CDC pipeline in a number of ways, including SQL-like code.
Apache Flink's documentation led me to my current solution, which must be incorrect for some reason.
